# Treating dependent timepoints as independent

Tags: repeated-measures, independence

I've been given a data set to work with that includes measurements of the same group of individuals over approximately 6 months (3 measurements total). The problem is that they did not include any method for linking the observations across measurements - there are no ID numbers, names, or variables that I can use for linkage. I've already gone back and forth about the data multiple times - it doesn't seem like linkage variables were recorded. Other than loss of power, are there problems with treating these measurements as independent that I'm not aware of (or better yet, are there ways of dealing with this problem that I'm not aware of)?

Thanks

Comment: This is tough, if the data are dependent then treating it as independent is wrong. This will give you smaller variances / CI / p-values, wrong inference. Although given that your data points are measured every 3 months, maybe there isn't much correlation left?

Comment: Unfortunately, variables like these will have Pearson correlations in the .4 - .6 range even when measured over years.

Comment: Then you are proverbially screwed. You can still analyze it without considering the correlation but the results will be dubious.